# android fragment replacing and removing

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have the following activity which produced 3 tabs, and put fragment in each one of them.

```
public class ClientActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_client);
        ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        ActionBar.Tab tabA = bar.newTab().setCustomView(R.layout.tab_a_layout);
        ActionBar.Tab tabB = bar.newTab().setCustomView(R.layout.tab_b_layout);
        ActionBar.Tab tabC = bar.newTab().setCustomView(R.layout.tab_c_layout);
        Fragment fragmentA = new firstTab();
        Fragment fragmentB = new secondTab();
        Fragment fragmentC = new thirdTab();
        tabA.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(fragmentA));
        tabB.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(fragmentB));
        tabC.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(fragmentC));
        bar.addTab(tabA);
        bar.addTab(tabB);
        bar.addTab(tabC);
    }

    protected class MyTabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
        private Fragment fragment;

        public MyTabsListener(Fragment fragment)
        {
            this.fragment = fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
        {
            ft.add(R.id.fragment_place, fragment, null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            ft.remove(fragment);            
        }
    }
}
```

in the first fragment (tabA) i have listview and listener which replacing the fragment on click.

when i am clicking on the second tab (after selecting line on the listview on tabA), the listener adding the tab instead of replacing it.
it happens because the TabUnsellected is removing the wrong fragment (it was first_tab, but replaced to test_tab on the listview selecting row).
how can i use the remove option on the ft on TabUnselected to remove the CURRENT fragment on the tab, assuming i have always 1 fragment on each tab?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by changing from ft.add to ft.replace on the TabSelected:

```
    ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fragment);
    ft.commit();
```